# nusoap_client in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

How can I add `nusoap_client` function to my Symfony 3 project? Is there any `Composer` command to do this?

I think it must be a bundle but I don't know that bundle name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **econea/nusoap** bundle with `composer require econea/nusoap`

Here is [link](https://github.com/econea/nusoap) to Github repository.

Comment: @morteza Error you are getting is caused by DNS resolution failure. You may try `composer self-update`,  but probably caused your network setting in your dev environment.

Comment: Thank you. Successfully downloaded and installed. But `nusoap_client()` function still does not working?

Comment: Run `php -i | grep -i soap` to check if you have soap ext installed and loaded.

Comment: Yes, it's installation